# How should I run compensations/rollback steps for a Saga Orchestration with Axon Framework?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, axon, saga

For a use case where I want to implement a Saga Orchestration for a couple services with Axon, I've built:

- order-service (saga orchestrator with **Spring boot + Axon Framework**)
- payment-service (microservice)
- shipping-service (microservice)

Then I have a class annotated with **@Saga** with 3 steps/event handlers:

- Order created (first service)
- Payment done (second service)
- Order shipped (third service)
- Order effectively created

My question is **how I'm supposed to rollback/compensate *all previous executed steps* if, for example, shipping service fails?**

From documentation I've got some doubts on:

- do I need to create a new class with @Saga?
- on the *service that failed* should I throw an Exception or send error to another Command/Event
- how should I call `SagaLifecycle.end()`

*That would be great to have a solution showing some code. Thanks!*

Comment: *That would be great to have a solution showing some code. Thanks!* - it would be great to have a question showing some code... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A well implemented Saga can deal with any faulty scenarios occurring from the transaction said Saga is managing. Thus, upon *any* operation dispatched from within the saga, you should be able to expect an exceptional case which you would react on. It is *this* reaction which is the compensating action you are looking for.

Now, to go over you exact questions:

> do I need to create a new class with @Saga?

Pretty confident that you do not need a new saga to resolve the exceptional cases in your domain. So no.

> on the service that failed should I throw an Exception or send error to another Command/Event

I would go either with an exception or an event here, not a command (as an (Axon) Saga does not handle commands). Whether you go either route depends on whether the event is a valuable business occurrence, thus requires to be stored indefinite in an event. Using an event will however mean you are splitting the fault tolerant behaviour of your Saga between distinct saga event handlers, which I personally wouldn't prefer. Thus, throwing an exception from one of the services to be handled by the saga would have my preference. Subsequently, if you need to store the exceptional occurrence, just publish an event next to it.

> how should I call SagaLifecycle.end()

Not sure what you are looking for with this question to be honest.
The `SagaLifecycle.end()` should be called once the Saga's lifecycle has ended. Thus, when that transaction is done. *When* it is done is entirely up to your domain and note something necessitated by the fact you need to dispatch a compensating action.

To clarify my intent, here's some (pseudo)code showing where I would perform the compensating action:

```java
private transient CommandGateway commandGateway;

@SagaEventHandler(assocationProperty = "some-association)
public void on(SomeEvent event) {
    // Validate/set state if necessary
    commandGateway.send(new SomeCommand(...))
                  .exceptionally(exception -> {
                      // Dispatch compensating action through service/CommandGateway
                  });
}
```

Comment: looks like exceptionally() do the work. about ending the SagaLifecycle, was that I wasn't sure about how to play with compensations in a single or multiple saga classes. thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate why `exceptionally()` doesn't work? That's unclear for me at the moment. Just to be exact, I am talking about this method: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally(java.util.function.Function)

Comment: Rollback in Saga Axon mean that we must to write an event to make the transaction undo in the database, for example: if we inserted it, now we must to delete it. Is it right? @Steven

Comment: @nobjta_9x_tq, that's right, although an event isn't always the right solution! Sometimes, a event to trigger the rollback by some other component is the way forward. In other times, performing a compensating action by invoking a service or dispatching a command (as in the code snippet I've shared) is the way forward. And yet other times, scheduling a task to (for example) retry at a later stage or check whether the initial action succeeded is _what_ to do.